# Can someone help me identify this plant

Tags: identification, flowers, bulbs

Please help me identify this plant that i saw.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why the houseplant tag has been applied, since these seem to be growing outdoors, but no matter - they are Eucomis, common name Pineapple Lily. Hard to be sure which variety they are, as they look like they're nearly over and there's no way of telling what colour they were, but there's just a hint that this one might be Eucomis comosa, see link for comparison purposes - there are other varieties with other colours (pink, yellow, a white flowered one called Eucomis autumnalis, etc) http://www.trecanna.com/Super.asp?id=434&name=Eucomis+comosa+-+Pineapple+Lily+-+1L+pot

Comment: sorry about the houseplant tag - new to this gardening site

Comment: S'okay - glad you removed it though, but it might have meant something - in the UK, we have to pot these up and overwinter indoors, at which point it might be considered a houseplant!